# Converting BeautifulSoup soup to lxml element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I would like to use `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` to parse some web pages. Since the raw data is not a clean `xml` so it cannot be parsed directly by `lxml.etree.fromstring`. However, `Beautifulsoup(page_source,'lxml')` works and I can get the soup data of the page. As I need some functions in `lxml` such as query by `xpath`. Are there any functions or variables that I can call to convert the `soup` object of the whole raw web page to a `etree` object? (I guess `Beautifulsoup` should have converted the raw page to an `etree` object before generating a `soup` object via `lxml` parser, but I cannot find out where it stores the object.)

p.s. I have tried the answer from [Is it possible to use bs4 soup object with lxml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52316737/is-it-possible-to-use-bs4-soup-object-with-lxml/52320065#52320065) to parse the web pages. But I still find some pages cannot be parsed, here is the example:

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> html = urlopen('https://www.nature.com/articles/s41558-019-0619-1').read()

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')  ## return a soup object

>>> from lxml.etree import fromstring    
>>> fromstring(soup.prettify()) ## return errors

>>> from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring    
>>> fromstring(soup.prettify()) ## return errors
```

Comment: what object are you looking for in the html? any html reference and link?

Comment: I'm still unsure of what you are looking for but this sounds similar : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52320065/12128167

Comment: Thank you for sharing another question. I need the `etree` element of the whole page just like what should return by `lxml.etree.fromstring(page_source)`.  But I found some page cannot be convert to that even via `lxml.html.fromstring(soup.prettify())`.

Comment: I have modified the question by adding an example.

Comment: If it's html, not xml, why not just parse it by the soup object itself?

Comment: I need to search some tags via `xpath` and it seems that soup object cannot do that.

Comment: perhaps tell us what you are after as xpath may not be needed.

Comment: I would like to extract the items with `href` tags that contains some keywords, I know I can iterate the whole elements to do that but still I prefer a `xpath` approach.

Comment: Can you provide a couple of examples of your desired outputs?

Comment: For the disired outputs of this question, I would like to get something like: `etree_obj = soup.etree()`. if it is impossible, then I want something that can query the elements via xpath like  `.//a[contains(@href,patterns)]` without iterating the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

lxml now has a function for converting a BeautifulSoup tree into lxml Element trees. You can do something like:

```
elems = lxml.html.soupparser.convert_tree(soup)
```

Where `elems` will be a list of lxml trees (not a single tree because soups can have multiple roots).

For more information, see: https://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.soupparser-module.html#convert_tree